# How can I animate a SVG (with a polygon, not a path)?

Tags: css, animation, svg

I've got an SVG which I'm trying to have "drawn" out on the page. But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it doesn't do anything.

Here's my SVG code:

```html
<svg width="1366px" height="534px" viewBox="0 0 1366 534" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <defs>
                        <linearGradient x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-1">
                            <stop stop-color="#0077C0" offset="0%"></stop>
                            <stop stop-color="#0581A6" offset="0%"></stop>
                            <stop stop-color="#5DB9E8" offset="100%"></stop>
                        </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                    <g id="Final-Option" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" class="path">
                        <g id="FCCC-HP" transform="translate(0.000000,-3117.000000)" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)">
                            <polygon id="Logo-Outlined" points="459.366212 3117 213.015827 3543.85325 136.72131 3411.78064 133.923592 3404.66263 -26 3680.75946 -19.4896353 3684.5416 133.243066 3420.85779 208.630216 3551.41755 213.015827 3558.98185 215.133019 3555.35098 459.366212 3132.12859 633.354006 3433.25567 727.871496 3597.40091 956.60382 3201.49319 1185.18492 3597.40091 1303.74766 3391.87897 1491.42158 3717 1498 3713.21029 1303.74766 3376.75794 1185.18492 3582.27988 956.60382 3186.35703 727.871496 3582.27988"></polygon>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
```

And here's the code(s) I've tried using:

https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: draw 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

I also tried this:

https://codepen.io/MyXoToD/post/howto-self-drawing-svg-animation

```
section.content .features .overlay svg{
    path,polygon{
        &#hood {
            stroke-dasharray:1000;
            stroke-dashoffset:1000;
            animation:draw 5s linear forwards
        }
    }
}

@keyframes draw{
    to{stroke-dashoffset:0}
}
```

I've never animated a SVG before, so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: A `polygon` is two dimensional, so you can't easily have the same effects as a `path`, that's why you `morph` a polygon. In your example, the `hill` polygon can be represented as path as well.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at morphing! If that's a no go, I'll see if I can change it from a polygon to a path :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, your file can not be animated, because the paths merge. Look, - a few nodal points are located together on the same vertices of the polygon.

[image]

I drew again, trying to keep your size and curve shape.

```html
   <svg  width="683" height="267" viewBox="0 0 1366 534" >
  
  <g id="Final-Option" fill="none" stroke="#5DB9E8" stroke-width="3"  class="path">
<g id="FCCC-HP" transform="translate(0.000000,-3117)" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"/>
<path id="check" d="M24 510 133 298 209 437 460 16 729 476 956 74l228 402 0 0 68-209 107 234 0 0"  />
  
  </g>
</svg>
```

To draw a line drawing animation, you need to know exactly its length.

```
<script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Path length - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

The length of the path turned out to be `2821px`

For the animation of the line we will use the patch attribute `stroke-dashoffset`

If you decrease the value of the attribute from the maximum value of 2821px to zero, the line will be drawn from zero to the final length.

### SVG solution

```html
<svg  width="683" height="267" viewBox="0 0 1366 534" >
  <defs> 
    <linearGradient x1="100" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" id="linearGradient-1">
      <stop stop-color="#0077C0" offset="0" id="stop7"/>
      <stop stop-color="#0581A6" offset="0" id="stop9"/>
      <stop stop-color="#5DB9E8" offset="100" id="stop11"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="Final-Option" fill="none" stroke="#5DB9E8" stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="2821" stroke-dasharray="2821" class="path">
    <g id="FCCC-HP" transform="translate(0.000000,-3117.000000)" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"/>
    <path id="check" d="M24 510 133 298 209 437 460 16 729 476 956 74l228 402 0 0 68-209 107 234 0 0"  >
 
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="2821;0" dur="5s" fill="freeze"  />
   </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### CSS solution

```css
#Final-Option {
    fill:none;
    stroke:#5DB9E8;
    stroke-dashoffset:2821;
    stroke-dasharray:2821;
    animation: Final_stroke 6s ease-in forwards;
        } 

    @keyframes Final_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2821;
    }
    100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="683" height="267" viewBox="0 0 1366 534" version="1" id="svg2">
 
    <linearGradient x1="100" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" id="linearGradient-1">
      <stop stop-color="#0077C0" offset="0" id="stop7"/>
      <stop stop-color="#0581A6" offset="0" id="stop9"/>
      <stop stop-color="#5DB9E8" offset="100" id="stop11"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="Final-Option" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="2821" stroke-dasharray="2821" class="path">
    <g id="FCCC-HP" transform="translate(0.000000,-3117.000000)" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"/>
    <path d="M24 510 133 298 209 437 460 16 729 476 956 74l228 402 0 0 68-209 107 234 0 0"  />
    
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Animating a polygon using an attribute `d`

Another technique of animation is used.

The original path is transformed in a vector editor, each time a path with new coordinates of nodes is stored.

This technique is described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47499175/7394871).

Below is the full code:

```html
<svg  width="683" height="267" viewBox="0 0 1366 534" >
 
  <g id="Final-Option" fill="none" stroke="#5DB9E8" stroke-width="3"  class="path">
    <g id="FCCC-HP" transform="translate(0.000000,-3117.000000)" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"/>
    <path id="check" d="M24 510 133 298 209 437 460 16 729 476 956 74l228 402 0 0 68-209 107 234 0 0"  >
 
  <animate attributeName="d" values="M24 510 133 298 209 437 460 16 729 476 956 74l228 402 0 0 68-209 107 234 0 0;M24 510 133 493 209 437 465 355 733 140 956 74l132 47 94-44 69 190 107 234 0 0;M24 510 137 148 284 441 460 222 735 298 956 383l173-96 58-30 64 9 107 234 0 0;M24 510 133 298 209 437 460 16 729 476 956 74l228 402 0 0 68-209 107 234 0 0" dur="12s" fill="freeze"  repeatCount="2" />
   </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Animation together with markers in the nodes of the polygon

```html
<svg  width="683" height="267" viewBox="0 0 1366 534" >
  <defs> 
   <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="10" refY="10"
        markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
        markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
        <polyline id="markerPoly1" points="0,0 20,10 0,20 2,10" fill="crimson" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <g id="Final-Option" fill="none" stroke="#5DB9E8" stroke-width="3"  class="path">
    <g id="FCCC-HP" transform="translate(0.000000,-3117.000000)" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"/>
    <path id="check" d="M24 510 133 298 209 437 460 16 729 476 956 74l228 402 0 0 68-209 107 234 0 0"   style=" marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow); marker-mid: url(#MarkerArrow); marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);">
 
  <animate attributeName="d" values="M24 510 133 298 209 437 460 16 729 476 956 74l228 402 0 0 68-209 107 234 0 0;M24 510 133 493 209 437 465 355 733 140 956 74l132 47 94-44 69 190 107 234 0 0;M24 510 137 148 284 441 460 222 735 298 956 383l173-96 58-30 64 9 107 234 0 0;M24 510 133 298 209 437 460 16 729 476 956 74l228 402 0 0 68-209 107 234 0 0" dur="12s" fill="freeze"  repeatCount="2" />
   </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Unfortunately, the last two examples can not be implemented using CSS animations

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and explanations of it all!

Comment: @LeanneSeawright Thank you. Ask more questions. Always happy to help.